# preg_replace different result between sql result and string

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, preg-replace

I have a strange problem with a simple preg_replace, if I use

```
$pattern = '/<div class="formula">(.*?)<\/div>/';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
```

not work correctly, nothing is replaced....if I put a static string instead of $str all work correctly.

```
string(2133) "Velocità: <div class="formulaTex">...</div><div class="formula">...</div>
```

why?there is some kind of encoding to use?

if I pass the var to preg_replace not work, if I pass the static string it work!

this is my code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:ARGOMENTI_NEW.sqlite');;
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Testi WHERE IDSezione = 100");
while($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $pattern = '/<div class="formula">(.*?)<\/div>/';
    $str = preg_replace($pattern, "", $row[0]["Testo"]);
    echo $str . "<br/><br/><br/>";

}
```

thanks

Comment: How do you expect us to answer if you don't post the strings? Definitely there is a difference, the question is _what_ difference. Might be some unicode characters looking similar.

Comment: Need to show us a `var_dump()` of your `$str` and `$pattern`

Comment: I update my question with the vardump of string and pattern!

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/7M9BEe

Comment: with static string work also on my code, the problem is when I try to get this string from a sqlite query...I update the question

Comment: First, try using the `/su` modifiers (`'/<div class="formula">(.*?)<\/div>/su'`). Second, is your `$str` really a string and not any array?

Comment: So you want to remove any `<div>` with class "formula" from the string? This looks like all of the string except for the first word.

Answer (score 0):

I find the error, the string from sql query stamp encoded html entity, on the screen I see the correct string but real string have different characters....this is the problem! whit this I solve:

```
$str = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", html_entity_decode($row[0]["Testo"]));
```